# Enable and Specify ttl for elasticsearch index using elasticsearch-py client

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

Can someone point me to the right direction to specify the elasticsearch index ttl time for documents, using the elasticsearch-py client ?

I tried the official documentation but that does not looks very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try giving ttl value as a parameter to [this](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html?highlight=TTL#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.create) create function ?

Answer (score 0):

The lib you are using must use the API under the cover:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-ttl-field.html (Note: this looks ** deprecated**, consider using `index-per-timeframe` as said by ES docs)

It is called `ttl`, so chances are you will find something by searching for `ttl` in the github repo of the lib: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=ttl

This worked well because `ttl` is a specific string which has little conflicts with other strings...